# How do I change to another view controller (clearly explained)

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin, viewcontroller

This is probably a stupid question, but as I haven't found an answer anywhere else I will ask it here.

My question is: How can I change which view controller is being viewed. In my case I want the user to open the app, and if the user hasn't already filled out the setup form the app will change from the **home page** to the **setup page**.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        //Initial setup check
        dataBase.SetBool(false, "setUpComplete");
        if (dataBase.BoolForKey("setUpComplete") == false)
        {
            //Code to change page here
        }
    }
```

Thanks to anyone who decides to answer this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    //Initial setup check
    dataBase.SetBool(false, "setUpComplete");
    if (dataBase.BoolForKey("setUpComplete") == false)
    {
       var objSetUpViewController=new SetUpViewController()
       this.NavigationController.PushViewController (objSetUpViewController, true);
    }
    else
    {
       //If setup completed move on HomeViewController
       var objHomeViewController=new HomeViewController()
       this.NavigationController.PushViewController (objHomeViewController, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I'm getting a bit caught up with where you would define the names for the ViewControllers. I have used the storyboard ID of both pages but it doesn't seem to work. If you could elaborate on that it would be much appreciated.

Comment: It would be great if you create another question(clearly explained) for that instead of dragging this thread . We would discus there.

Comment: Add new ViewController by right clicking on your project like HomeViewController..etc